# Blender models appear in UDK asset manager, but not in game

Tags: blender, udk

I am new to UDK and blender. I am using UDK3.

I have tried the following so far:

1. Making the mesh origin, (0,0,0)
2. Making the parent bone origin (0,0,0)
3. Parenting the root bone with the mesh

I have tried exporting in the following file formats:

*.psk
*.fbx

Both fbx and psk import into the UDK asset manager, and are viewable in the asset manager. I have also previewed my weapon Im importing against a chracter model, and it appears to be slightly too large (which is easy to fix). Many other forums mentioned for other people that the models might be displaying but be very very small.

I have tried viewing in:

- 3rd person
- 1st person (Weapon factory, and giving weapon via console command)

I have made the blender file avaliable here: http://www.fileswap.com/dl/m1BiH78Gba/

The code is just standard wizard generated code and has worked previously for other weapon models.

Any ideas or clues about how I can go about trouble shooting this would be greatly appreciated.